# Rails Asset Pipeline not compiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In my application.js file, I have the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require vendor
```

When I load up a Rails server with `rails s` the application.js file that is served still has the require statements at the top.  I expect it to remove these lines and load the jquery file separately.

I'm using Rails 3.2.19.  My RAILS_ENV is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not entirely sure that what you're doing doesn't work, I typically use `//= require [name of js file]`. e.g. `//= require bootstrap.js` when `bootstrap.js` is inside the `vendors/javascript` folder.

Comment: The application.js file compiles okay for my colleagues.  There's something about my environment.

Comment: perhaps that name is cause for trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an old version of Ruby? Maybe something from before 1.9.3? I had similar before problems when upgrading Rails without upgrading Ruby.

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.1.2p95

Answer (score 0):

Bug with sprockets 2.2.1

Updated to sprockets 2.2.2 (via bundle update sprockets) and it now works